# Spring Boot forward to intended page after login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

On my index page, I display multiple products. In order to view the products in details, people need to log in first.

Let's say my index page's url is: "/" and product details page is: "/products/{id}".

My question is how can I get into the product details page after log in?

I have tried to check for header referer to get previous url which if I click the on the product item on the index page, the header referer is "/".
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can set redirection on successful login. May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243352/how-to-set-redirection-after-successful-login.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I have searched for the solution before ask, most of them are redirect the page to previous request, which I can achieve that. My problem is forward to the page that I request not redirect to the page that make the request.

Comment: Are you using any front-end framework?

Comment: @SandeepKumar just jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it. One simple way is when redirected to the login page. (This is my understanding of the problem you are describing) you pass as param the id of the product or the path you want to redirect the user too. and once the user logs in you redirect the user to what the param used to say. So when you show the login page you would have `http://yourdomain.com/login?ref=/products/12` and after the user sucessfully logs in you would check for the ref param and redirect him there.

Take a look at this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login

**ANSWERING YOUR QUESTION**
So I don't understand what you cant get it from refer. But asuming you dont care, or want to use an alternative option, You could: When rendering the list of products you know the user is not logged in. So each link to the product detail can have a param concatenated to it like so
`http://yourdomain.com/login?ref=/products/12`

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/login?ref=/products/12"> product detail</a>
```

and then on the spring side you would so something similar too :

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {

            response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("ref"));

    }
```

You should probably add additional checks if the parameter is not null etc. or for user roles. Not sure im kind of guessing your intent.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have read the article but it is not applicable to my problem. Your solution may work, but how can I get the product link in my LoginController? The header referer is "/".

Comment: In what way is it not applicable? It answers the question but you seem to want to do it some other way. header-referer give you the URL of the resource containing the link whereas it seems that what you actually want to do is redirect to the security protected URL requested - as outlined in the article.