# Why Spring Security getAuthentication() returns null on server

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have a web application and use spring security for authentication.
All page need authentication, but Login page doesn't need  authentication.
in my situation, I succeeded to access other page which need authentication after login on local environment. But I fail on server environment.Because the getAuthentication() returns null.
 **I don't know why the getAuthentication() returns null on server environment.**

when move to /foo after login(local log)

```
[2021-11-11 15:20:05:32506][http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication - Authenticated user
[2021-11-11 15:20:05:32507][http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication - Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@12234790), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33756][http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.log - Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,246] milliseconds.
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33760][http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@12234790), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@16178716]
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33760][http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@12234790), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@16178716]
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33760][http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
--move to foo
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33769][http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal - Securing GET /foo
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33769][http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@12234790), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]]
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33769][http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@12234790), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]]
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33769][http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler - Mapped to com.bar.view.controller.FooController#initalize()
--success
[2021-11-11 15:20:06:33770][http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation - Authorized filter invocation [GET /foo] with attributes [authenticated]
```

when move to /foo after login(server log). sorry no method name on log

```
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126723][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@708afefc), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=39.110.214.222, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126740][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@708afefc), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=39.110.214.222, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4d6cfed4]
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126740][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoginUser(loginInfo=com.bar.entity.LoginInfoEntity@708afefc), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=39.110.214.222, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4d6cfed4]
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126741][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
-- move to foo
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126766][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /foo
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126766][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126766][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126767][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.bar.view.controller.RobotSelectController#initalize()
-- fail
[2021-11-11 06:17:15:126780][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /foo] with attributes [authenticated]
```

My source code

I have only Config and  for Spring Security

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/css/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .mvcMatchers(loginPage).permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
              .formLogin()
               .loginPage(loginPage)
               .loginProcessingUrl(loginSuccessUrl)
               .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        //add Session
                        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(180000);
                        //move page
                        response.sendRedirect(fooPage);
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Login implement UserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class Login implements UserDetailsService{
    
    
    private final LoginInfoRepository loginRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    public Login(LoginInfoRepository loginRepo) {
        this.loginRepo = loginRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LoginInfoEntity entity = loginRepo.findById(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("not exist user"));
        
        UserDetails userDetails = new LoginUser(entity);
        
        return userDetails; 
    }
    
}
```

loginUser use for session information

```
public class LoginUser extends User {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public LoginUser(LoginInfoEntity loginInfo) {
        super(loginInfo.getUserId(), loginInfo.getPassword(), 
                loginInfo.isAvailable(), true, true, true, Collections.EMPTY_SET);
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thank you Arthur Klezovich. **The cause is contextpath** not redirect. I thought local environment is equal to server environment. but Server environment had contextpath Beacuse I don't set for contextpath.
It causes url to be involved contextpath.

For example)

- **Succeed** to get session after login in local - http://99.99.99/foo
- **Failed** to get session after login in server - http://99.99.99/foo(question's url)
- **Succeed** to get session after login in server -http://99.99.99/contextpath/foo

There are several ways remove url of contextpath. I choosed easiest way change file of war name

```
foo.war -> root.war
```

after Spring-security is working well, no modify code

Answer (score 1):

> [2021-11-11 06:17:15:126766][foo] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

This is the key line to understand the issue.
When you are doing the redirect you are redirecting the user, yes.
However, his session information ( cookie ) or some other thing is not part of this redirected request.

Therefore, to the `/foo` endpoints point of view, it does not get any credential information and its treating the request as anonymous.

If you can get rid of this piece of code ...

```
successHandler(.. do redirect ...)
```

And don't do the redirect like this and do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243352/how-to-set-redirection-after-successful-login) instead, it will likely fix the problem.

Redirect via `defaultSuccessUrl`

```
 http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/success.html", true);
```

Does this solve your problem ? Tell me in the comments.

You can also enable HTTP request tracing and see exactly which request with which headers and payloads are coming to the `/foo` endpoint and this will make it easier to diagnose the problem.

Are you using cookies or JWT for authentication ? Tell me in the comments.

Comment: Thnak you for your anwer. I'm not using cookies or JWT for authentication. that codes are all. defaultSuccessUrl Thank you . I am concerned Because I tried moving page through direct input http://xxxx/foo after login, but I was fail. anyway I will try your answer.

Comment: @Carmel tell me if it works

Comment: I tried it. Thank you it works well. but I need 「request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(180000)」 , I should update 180000 or any interval. Beacsue I should use successHandler instead of defaultSuccessUrl.

Comment: You can set it in another way by using this http object, without needing to rely on the servlet API